# Writing Accented Latin Letters in a Font with Cyrillic Alphabet

Tags: fonts, xetex, accents, cyrillic

I am having what I think is a LaTeX problem but might just be a font issue. I'm using the font Quant Antiqua, which has both Cyrillic and Latin alphabets and I'm trying to write the name "Élie Cartan." But using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\setromanfont[
BoldFont=bold.ttf,
ItalicFont=ital.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=boldital.ttf,
]{plain.ttf}

\begin{document}
Élie Cartan \\
\'{E}lie Cartan
\end{document}
```

both output a Cyrillic letter instead of the desired Latin letter with accent. Is there a simple way around this? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A minimal example of code is needed. How do you use the font? With XeLaTeX?

Comment: Indeed, with XeLaTeX. Would it help for me to include the preamble?

Comment: Definitely so. As small as it is necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: you should not use `inputenc`  (but that is not the problem, it just gives a warning and does nothing withe xetex) it sounds like the font that you have is not a Unicode encoded font but has the cyrillic in the slots between 128 and 256 matching a legacy 8bit encoding, such a font is not ideally suited to xetex

Comment: Thanks; is there otherwise a way to force it to display the É character anyway? I'm totally fine with a hacky solution.

Comment: As far as I can see, Quant Antiqua is a commercial font distributed by Paratype, which produces good TrueType fonts, with proper encodings. This makes me suspect about the source of your, apparently not Unicode encoded, version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hacky way of achieving the desired result:

```
$\acute{\mathrm{E}}$lie Cartan
```

Comment: Ugh. If this is really needed I wouldn't use the font.

Comment: That is fine, I am not asking you to use the font :)